# How to cut a hierarchy cluster tree by a given maximum within cluster distance?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I am working on a one-dimensional gene positions data which is like

> [705118, 705118, 832132, 860402, 865710, 867206, 925364, 925364,925364]

(around 2000 items in one array) and I wanna divide the array into clusters with a maximum within cluster distance less or equal to 2000.

So I used the

```
chrd=scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(chrn,metric='euclidean')
```

to get the distance matrix and then

```
scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(chrd,method='average',metric='euclidean')
```

to get the linkage matrix.

But there is no such function in scipy.cluster.hiearchy.fcluster can cut the hierarchy tree based the the maximum within cluster distance.

Does anyone have any idea about how to handle this?
I try to rewrite a hierarchy algorithm which can include such threshold but it seems to be really hard to do >.<

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use **complete linkage** if you need a maximum distance of objects, not average.

Then cut the tree at the desired height.

Alternatively, you can also implement Leader clustering. It's stupid, but he maximum distance is twice the distance of the cluster radius there.

Answer (score -1):

If using scikit-learn is a possibility, you could check out http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html

it has a parameter that limits the distance between two samples

Comment: DBSCAN does not guarantee a maximum-within distance. It computes the transitive closure, so distances will be much larger than epsilon.